# Use of "develop"

Tags: word-choice

Per Merriam-Webster, **[develop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/develop)**:

> to cause (something) to grow or become bigger or more advanced

Given the above definition of the term **develop**, I would like to know if it can be used in the following context:

> Consider a group of students. They are studying for an upcoming math test by doing a number questions.

In this scenario, is it accurate to say that they are **developing** their math skills - in terms of accuracy and speed.

*Note: I am confident that it is correct; however, a friend disagrees and I would like to know who is correct.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use "developing" it suggests that their skills were previously not developed i.e. not very good. One possible alternative would be "honing". This word suggests that their skills were already good but just needed sharpening.